# How to Upload video files in background?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I am doing a app in which i need to upload videos taken from iPhone Camera and upload it to a server. When the app is in foreground the video gets uploaded but i don't know how to do it in background when the app is inactive. I used `AFNetworking` to do the multipart data upload. Here is the code i tried

```
var task:NSURLSessionUploadTask!
let FILEPICKER_BASE_URL = "My server Url"
var isUploading : Bool = false
var videoPath : String!
func upload(dictMain: NSMutableDictionary)
{
    isUploading = true
    let uuid =  NSUUID().UUIDString + "-" + (getUserId().description)
    let request = AFHTTPRequestSerializer().multipartFormRequestWithMethod("POST", URLString: FILEPICKER_BASE_URL, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (fromData) in

        do {
            try fromData.appendPartWithFileURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath) , name: "fileUpload", fileName: uuid, mimeType: "video/quicktime")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
        }, error: nil)

    let manager:AFURLSessionManager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("Your video is uploading"));

    task = manager.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil , completionHandler: { (response, responseObject, error) in
            NSLog("Resposne Object: \(responseObject)")
            post(dictMain,response: responseObject!)
    })
    task.resume()    
}
```

Also I don't know how to know my upload progress. I tried to use the following block in the progress parameter

```
 { (progress) in
    print("\((progress))")
 }
```

But it does not work the complier shows error 
`Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> _' to expected argument type 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>' (aka 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<NSProgress>>')`

Could any one share a snippet that really works. As i googled there are very very few basic tutorials on `NSURLSession.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest` and all of them i tried didn't work on swift 2.2

I am using Xcode 7.3 Swift 2.2

> Points I Know:

1. Background upload works only with File paths and not `NSData`. so i took the video url path from the `UIImagePickerController` function `func video(videoPath: NSString, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo info: AnyObject)`
2. To do background file transfer i have to enable them in the `Target`->`Capabilities` -> `Background Modes` -> `Background fetch`
3. Must set the Session manager with `NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("")`. But i don't know why and where that identifier is being used.

I know this is a long post. But if it is answered this will surely be helpful to many developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling the upload function inside a `DispatchQueue Background queue`

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { upload() }
```